# Wordpress Data Entry Plugin

Tags: database, wordpress, post

I am looking to make a database of zoning projects that are searchable by different variables such as date, type of meeting, address, applicant name, type of variance, etc.  I would like to do this utilizing the Wordpress framework as much as possible.  Is there a way to efficiently do this using custom post types, tags, categories, archive pages, etc such that posts may be assigned a value for each variable, and then filtered appropriately through a search query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Primarily Search wordpress site for "post search" or "data entry"

If you are not able to choose one, you can try the following :

- Advance custom post search [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-post-search/)  ||| For search
- Geo Data Store http://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-data-store/  ||Best for your project!

In addidtion to above you may use this plugin - Ajax search

---

Above options only cover wordpress plugins which can only be used in wordpress sites.